# Tengo un problema en vue. Estoy creando una aplicación y cuando actualizo o presiono F5 en cuaquier pagina me redirecciona siempre al home

Tags: vue.js, router

Estoy creando una aplicacion en vue y no logro que cuando se visite una pagina cualquiera y se actualice la misma se recargue la página. Siempre que actualizo cualquier pagina la aplicacion me redirecciona al home. Que podria ser?

Comment: Sugiero un recorrido de bienvenida para elaborar una buena pregunta que sea admitida: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.